# raphael how to move text

Tags: javascript, text, raphael

I have some text and I want to move it up using the Raphael library. However is there also a way of moving it up after 3 seconds or something like that.

```
var t1 = paper.text(700, 168, "Hi");
t1.attr({fill:"white"});
```

I tried to use this code so that it would move the text up however it did not.

```
t1.animate({cy: 10 , cx: 700}, 10000);
```

I just wanted to ask the same thing for the curve path.

```
        var curvePath = paper.path("M690,124s20,15 10,19Z");
    curvePath.attr({fill:"orange"});
```

And i have tried the same thing but i guess i got wrong things again.

```
    curvePath.animate({m: 10 , z: 700}, 10000);
```

Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place of,

```
t1.animate({cy: 10 , cx: 700}, 10000);
```

Use this,

```
t1.animate({y: 10 , x: 700}, 10000);
```

Paper has `x` and `y`attributes , not `cx` and `cy`.

[Reference](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text)

***Edit (after comment):***

From the same reference, I've given

```
var t1 = paper.text(700, 168, "Hi");
t1.attr({fill:"white"});
var anim = Raphael.animation({y: 10 , x: 700}, 10000)
t1.animate(anim.delay(5000));   // animation will start after 5 seconds.
```

Comment: ah thanks but just a quick question how do i delay this so it runs in like 5 seconds after the animation starts?

Comment: I've updated my answer, do check it. Please mark as answer if it helps you :)

Comment: That is great mate much apprentice it. How do i rate u up it says i have to have at least 15 rep :P Also if its not to much trouble could u answer my question below is well . Thanks again for the help!

Comment: to rate up just click ^ mark above `0` (where you marked as answer)

Comment: Ah wont let me , must have at least 15 rep sorry mate :(